# Thymeleaf #strings.trim() doesn't work

Tags: string, thymeleaf, trim

In short: I'm getting data from google places api and want to create entity in my db based on it. I have @Email annotation on a username field, so it can't contain white spaces. I was trying to use something like this:

```
th:value="${#strings.trim(place.name) + '@mywebsite.com'}"
```

But, it seems not work... I also tried different methods, just to double check if syntax is correct, on #strings like:

```
th:value="${#strings.toLowerCase(place.name) + '@mywebsite.com'}"
```

and its works just fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The example with .toLowerCase() works with place that has single word as a name, but starts with capital letter

Comment: What does "it seems not work" mean? Trim removes whitespace at the beginning and end of a string, are you expecting it to remove whitespace in the middle?  Perhaps string.replace would be more useful?

Comment: @Metroids you right.. my mistake. Can you share syntax example?

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming by the latest comments that you want to replace white spaces, something like:

> **this is an email** to **thisisanemail**

You can try:

```
th:value="${#strings.replace(place.name,' ','') + '@mywebsite.com'}"
```

The above code is an example of how to do it in thymeleaf but, in my opinion, you should handle it in the backend.

Comment: Works like charm! agree about doing it on a backend, but for prototype its good enough. Also How i can use second method, toLowerCase(), on it?

Comment: In one line? I will guess something like: `th:value="${#strings.toLowerCase(#strings.replace(place.name,' ','')) + '@mywebsite.com'}"` but not sure if it will work, let me know to update the answer. Also, take a look into [this post](https://vvirlan.wordpress.com/2015/10/04/thymeleaf-strings-utility-method-for-string-objects/) it will help you.